# SharePoint 2013 - Detect if user logs in for the 1st time or 100th time

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there an OOTB feature that allows UI developers to know if a specific user logs in for the first time or the 100th time.  Reason being is that I would like to to post a message on a custom page layout if it's the user's first time signed in (either with jQuery, or asp role based layers, or with the loginView).  Is there an easy way to detect and go about this process without diving into server side custom coding?

FYI - I do not have My Sites enabled so that area of SharePoint is not an option in my specific case.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about any audit log that can provide this information.

An easy option that comes to my mind is using a hidden custom list.

1. Create a hidden custom list which has fields (User, LoginCount, LastLogin etc)
2. On Home Page - Add a script which will add/update data into this list

This approach works only if the user comes directly to the home page.

Another option is to place the script in master page itself.

Comment: This sounds very interesting.  Would you happen to have a good reference on creating "hidden" custom lists?  That may help me to get started.  thanks!

Comment: You can use SharePoint Designer. And use that to hide it from Browser.